# Is there an algorithm for the satisfiability problem for a specific dictionary

Tags: logic, algorithms, first-order-logic, satisfiability

> Let $\Sigma = \left\{ c,g(,),R_1(),\ldots,R_k() \right\}$. Given a sentence (a formula with no free variables) $\varphi$ above $\Sigma$, is there an algorithm to check if $\varphi$ is satisfiable?

I've understood one approach could be showing a contradiction to the general satisfiability problem. Meaning, assuming by a contradiction that there's such an algorithm and utilizing for the general problem (Which we know isn't decidable)

I'd be glad if you could help me with that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your notation correctly, you have a binary function $g$ and several unary predicates $R_i$. With this vocabulary, you can write a first-order sentence saying that $g$ is a pairing function, i.e., every element is of the form $g(x,y)$ for a unique $x$ and $y$.  Using a pairing function, you can encode binary (or higher-arity) relations as unary ones; just represent a binary $P$ by the unary $R$ such that $R(g(x,y))\iff P(x,y)$. With arbitrary-arity relations available, you can use the usual proof of undecidability for unrestricted vocabularies.

Comment: How would you do the same trick for an higher-arity? Also, you used some $R$ for the purpose of encoding $P$. Given that you have only $k$ relations, how would you encode a formula with more than $k$ relations? Thanks!

Comment: Higher arities are not a problem, because you can code, for example, 5-tuples by $g(u,g(v,g(x,g(y,z))))$. Once you have higher arities, you can code, for example, two binary relations $P,Q$ into one ternary relation $R$, where $R(x,y,z)$ means $P(x,y)$ if $z=c$ and $Q(x,y)$ if $z\neq c$. (Actually, none of this is needed because, if I remember correctly, a single binary relation is enough for undecidability.)